# Fragmentation of one specific index is increasing too often

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a large table and it has more than 10 indexes. I have a fragmentation problem on one specific index. In the day hours, thousands of rows are being inserted in this table and the fragmentation of just one specific index is increasing very frequently. Other indexes are OK (maybe 0.01% per hour), but this specific index is increasing like 3 - 4% per hour ! It will probably be like 50 - 60% at the end of the day.

Can you help me to find out why this index is increasing too often.

----- Fill factor

This specific index: 0%

Other index (that has no problem about increasing): 90%

----- Index details;

- non-clustured
- 2 index key columns: (bit and nvarchar(100) type columns)
- 1 included column: (int) FK_OrderID (foreign key for another table)
- number of rows in the table : 6.5 million
- size of the table: 6.2 gb

and SHOWCONTIG details for the table;

- Pages Scanned................................: 805566
- Extents Scanned..............................: 100877
- Extent Switches..............................: 108951
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 8.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 92.42% [100696:108952]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 1.43%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 19.82%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 983.4
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 87.85%

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specification of this index ? (number of index key columns and included columns, clustered or non-clustered index, number of total rows in the table)

Comment: you are right, i forgot to give the details. now i edited the post, can you read from there? thanks

Comment: Maybe it's due to nvarchar(100). When do you perform reorganize and rebuild Indexes ?

Comment: @liotims normally i do it everyday at once. this issue happened yesterday. index maintanence job failed, i dig into the task and i realised that the job was stuck bcs the table was locked by index rebuilding process. Then i found out that the problem is this index because i could not rebuild it. when i try to rebuild, it just locks the table and never ends. then i use reorganize command and success ! today, the fragmentation value is over %20 already so far... i need to find out whats wrong with this index. i need it to rebuilded every night authomaticly and without errors.

Comment: Which edition of MSSQL is it ? If it's enterprise you can try to rebuild with ONLINE option. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177442(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @liotims its sql 2012 standard edition..

Comment: You can try to drop index and recreate it (rebuild index normaly work this way  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/22/sql-server-difference-between-index-rebuild-and-index-reorganize-explained-with-t-sql-script/). As it is a large table it can take long time.

Comment: Fill factor of 0 is the same as 100, so there is no space for updates.  Changes due to inserts should not be affected by fillfactor see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/.  I would drop the fillfactor to 95 or 90 then see if that improves the rebuild time and subsequent fragmentation rate.  It may help to have a job that runs throughout the day at intervals, reorganizing if the fragmentation increases above 5%.  This may slow the rate of fragmentation.  You could try creating a copy of a dev server and testing these ideas by generating a test load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by setting fillfactor value = 80. Thanks for replies